# Reference request: seminal paper on the Blumenthal-Getoor index

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes

Numerous papers are referring to the following one

*R. M. Blumenthal and R. K. Getoor, Sample functions of stochastic processes with stationary independent increments, J. Math. Mech. 10 (1961), 493–516*

in the literature, where they authors define what is now referred as the Blumenthal-Getoor index. However, I couldn't find this reference in the traditional databases, either on the website of this journal (does it still exist?).

Does anyone have some information to find this paper?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The journal changed name and Mathscinet doesn't yet link to its archive -- where your paper is [freely available](http://www.iumj.indiana.edu/IUMJ/fulltext.php?year=1961&artid=10031&volume=10).